# how to fill an input with html code with AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, forms, rest

I can't understand why this is not working.

I have an input in my site which is filled by an ajax request.

I would like to fill it with htmlCode, but it's empty when tried.

```
<form name="form" id="form" method="post" action="secondpage" />
    <input type="hidden" name="htmlCode" id="htmlCode"/>  
</form>


$.ajax({
    url : url,
    type: "POST",
    async: true,
    data : {
        "requestData": JSON.stringify(request) 
    },
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){ 
        var response = data.methodResult;
        alert(response.htmlCode);
        document.getElementById("htmlCode").value = response.htmlCode;
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

    } 
});
```

the alert shows the htmlCode, so, I'm sure it exists.

I read the variable in jsp:

```
System.out.println("htmlCode Value - " + request.getParameter(htmlCode));
```

And this is empty.

If I change the REST server, and returns "hello" instead of htmlCode it is filled.

Is there any forbidden character I'm trying to set or something?

I got the solution, I should encode UTF-8 the html text

Comment: what is the value of `response.htmlCode` you are getting.?

Comment: can you see the html code in the input box, servers don't usually allow html content in the textboxes,it leads to sql injection and other problems.

Comment: In input box, you can't put HTML, it only supports text. If you want to show html content, use DIV or SPAN, if you wan you can style your DIV look similar like a text box using CSS.

Comment: I'm not showing it, its an hidden input, I want it to send the data to second page, so, it's just for reading from jsp

Answer (score 1):

Does it work when you use JSON.stringify?

```
document.getElementById("htmlCode").value = JSON.stringify(response.htmlCode);
```

Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Answer (score -1):

Try this one

```
$.ajax({
    url : url,
    type: "POST",
    async: true,
    data : {
       "requestData": JSON.stringify(request) 
    },
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){ 
        document.getElementById("htmlCode").value = data;
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {} 
});
```

Comment: thanks but that's not the same! I want to get a field in the response

Comment: You can get JSON from server and create elements from data, i think this version is better then previews )

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.